# What is the actual value of JAVA_HOME used by Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in My Android Studio  from File>Project Structure >SDK Location  I see the below JDK Location :

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Everything works fine.

But I am confused due to other JAVA versions present on my PC :

on doing java-version on command prompt I get this :

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

and on doing where is java I get the below :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

in My Computers's Environment Path I have defined the JAVA_HOME as below in both user variable and Environmental variable

```
C:\Progra~\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

When I am trying to execute gradlew tasks , I get the below error :

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

What is the actual value of JAVA_HOME used by Android Studio and where I need to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally inorder to run Java applications we set JAVA_HOME value to java sdk directory/bin

Traditionally, JAVA_HOME is set to the JRE or SDK main directory.

That is because your PATH is wrong. Your PATH needs to point to the bin/ directory within your Java SDK. My guess is that your PATH is referencing JAVA_HOME, but assuming (incorrectly) that JAVA_HOME points to that bin/ directory. Just change your PATH to ensure that it picks up the bin/ directory.

Comment: you mean point to bin of  : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 not JRE as it is already pointing to JRE?